# Get selected data and fill textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make easy-to-use form for the users who are using our internal application. Basicly I have a select element. What I want is when I choose anything I want to fill specified text boxes.

Codes are below. That works fine but fill only 1 box.Pls do not forget normally I am getting data from the mySQL db.

**html file:**

```
<script src="choose.js"></script>
<select onchange="ChooseGuest(this.value)">
<option value="1">guest 1</option>
<option value="2">guest 2</option>
<option value="3">guest 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="guestdetails"/>
<input type="text" id="guestdetails2"/>
```

**php data file:**

```
$AskForIt = $_GET["q"];
If ($AskForIt == "1") {
echo "guest 1 data";
} Elseif ($AskForIt == "2") {
echo "guest 2 data";
} Elseif ($AskForIt == "3") {
echo "guest 3 data";
}
```

**js file:**

```
var xmlHttp

function ChooseGuest(str)
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("upgrade your browser");
  return;
  }
var url="guests.php";
url=url+"?q="+str;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("guestdetails").value=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

Comment: you can use jQuery AJAX instead of HTTP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This code looks at first glance correct. What specifically is not working or how can people help?

Comment: Your code is only set up to fill the first box as seen here document.getElementById("guestdetails").value=xmlHttp.responseText;

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to fill the input boxes with data pulled from your DB and have the appropriate data shown depending on which drop down is selected. PHP is server side only. Once the page loads the PHP will only run once and not again until the page is reloaded. So, you'll need to access those vars using JS. This is probably why only the first selection is being filled.

If this is so, you will need to go into your PHP  file and create JS vars that are equal to the data accessed from the DB. Simply set your JS vars equal to a PHP echo of the vars from your php:

**PHP Data File**

```
<?php

    var somePHPvar = "DB Value";

?>

<script> 

    var someVar = <?php echo somePHPvar; ?>; 


</script>
```

If this is all done on the same PHP file, don't forget to include it on the page and call these JS vars. From there you'll be able to fill those values using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do this with just jQuery.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u2gqwfL4/

**JavaScript**

```
var myData = [
  "guest 1 data",
  "guest 2 data",
  "guest 3 data"
];
$(function() {
  function ChooseGuest(v, str) {
    // Example AJAX Post call in jQuery
    // Replace '/echo/json/' with 'guests.php'
    // or use $.get() in the same way
    $.post("/echo/json/", {
      json: JSON.stringify(myData),
      q: str
    }, function(results) {
      console.log(results, v);
      $("#guestdetails" + v).val(results[v - 1]);
    });
  }
  $("#guestSelect option").click(function() {
    var selVal = parseInt($(this).val());
    var selText = $(this).html();
    ChooseGuest(selVal, selText);
  });
});
```

Your code will be a bit different due to the nature of jsfiddle and the way exampled are made. I would suggest:

```
  function ChooseGuest(v, str) {
    $.get("guests.php", {
      q: str,
      sid: Math.random()
    }, function(results) {
      console.log(results, v);
      $("#guestdetails" + v).val(results);
    });
  }
```